# Outlook 2010 email rendering

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

i am trying to set a global font in an email. The Mail is built using tables to keep compatibility but there is one table that just does not accept my styles. What I have done:

```
{literal}
<style>
    *,table, div, p, td, tr, #tabledetails, .tabledetails {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
</style>
{/literal}

...

<table id="tabledetails" class="tabledetails" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">...

<td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_quantity} x</td>
```

So as you see I tried about everything i could to set the font (and not use Times New Roman like Outlook loves to do) but it still doesnt work. What else can i possibly do?

---- edit ----- complete email ----

```
<link href="{$_system_mail_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
{literal}
<style>
*,table, div, p, td, tr, #tabledetails, .tabledetails {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
{/literal}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="email_container" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: justify;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="email_toplogo">
        <div class="email_toplogo"><img src="{$_system_logo_url}" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="email_table_left_bg" valign="top">
        <div class="email_table_left"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="email_table_center_bg" valign="top">
        <div class="email_content">
        <h1>Hallo {$order_data.delivery_firstname} {$order_data.delivery_lastname},</h1>
        <p>vielen Dank für Ihre Bestellung im Onlineshop von super cool company name i shouldnt tell anyone ;).
                      Wir werden Ihre Bestellung schnellstmöglich ausführen. Sie bekommen bei jeder Statusänderung Ihrer Bestellung eine automatisch generierte Email.</p>
                      <hr>
                 <P>Nachfolgend finden Sie Ihre Bestelldetails zur Kontrolle:</p>
        <p>{txt key=TEXT_ORDER_NUMBER}: {$order_data.orders_id}</p>
        <p>{txt key=TEXT_ORDER_DATE}: {$order_data.date_purchased}</p>
<p>E-Mail: {$order_data.customers_email_address}</p>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="shippingaddress">
        <h2>{txt key=TEXT_SHIPPING_ADDRESS}</h2>
        <p>{if $order_data.delivery_company}
        {$order_data.delivery_company}<br />
        {/if} {$order_data.delivery_firstname} {$order_data.delivery_lastname}<br />
        {$order_data.delivery_street_address}<br />
        {if $order_data.delivery_suburb} {$order_data.delivery_suburb}<br />
        {/if} {$order_data.delivery_postcode} {$order_data.delivery_city}<br />
        {if $order_data.delivery_state}{$order_data.delivery_state}
        {/if}{$order_data.delivery_country}<br />
        </p>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="paymentaddress">
        <h2>{txt key=TEXT_PAYMENT_ADDRESS}</h2>
        <p>{if $order_data.billing_company} {$order_data.billing_company}<br />
        {/if} {$order_data.billing_firstname} {$order_data.billing_lastname}<br />
        {$order_data.billing_street_address}<br />
        {if $order_data.billing_suburb} {$order_data.billing_suburb}<br />
        {/if} {$order_data.billing_postcode} {$order_data.billing_city}<br />
        {if $order_data.billing_state}{$order_data.billing_state}
        {/if}{$order_data.billing_country}<br />
        </p>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    {if $payment_info}<hr><h2>{txt key=TEXT_PAYMENT_INFOS}</h2>
        <p>{$payment_info}</p>{/if} 
        <hr>
<table id="tabledetails" class="tabledetails" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">
            <tr class="headerrow">
                <td class="left">{txt key=TEXT_QTY}</td>
                <td class="left">{txt key=TEXT_ARTICLE}</td>
                <td class="left">{txt key=TEXT_PRODUCTS_MODEL}</td>
                <td class="right">{txt key=TEXT_SINGLE_PRICE}</td>
                <td class="right">{txt key=TEXT_TOTAL_PRICE}</td>
            </tr>
            {foreach name=aussen item=order_values from=$order_products}
            <tr class="{cycle values="contentrow1,contentrow2"}">
                <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_quantity} x</td>
                <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_name}</strong></td>
                <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_model}</td>
                <td class="right" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_price.formated}</td>
                <td class="right" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">{$order_values.products_final_price.formated}</td>
            </tr>
            {$order_values.products_information.html_content}
            {/foreach}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right" class="subtotal">
                <div align="right">
                <p>{txt key=TEXT_SUB_TOTAL}: {$total.product_total.formated}</p>
                {foreach name=aussen item=order_total_values from=$order_total_data}
                <p>{$order_total_values.orders_total_name}:
                {$order_total_values.orders_total_price.formated}</p>
                {/foreach} {foreach name=aussen item=tax_data from=$total.total_tax}
                <p>{txt key=TEXT_TAX} {$tax_data.tax_key}%:
                {$tax_data.tax_value.formated}</p>
                {/foreach}
                <p><span class="doubleline">{txt key=TEXT_TOTAL}: {$total.total.formated}</span></p>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
<hr>
        <div class="email_footer">{$_system_footer_html}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="email_table_right_bg" valign="top">
        <div class="email_table_right"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---- edit 2 ---- the produced code for the product listing part

```
<table id="tabledetails" class="tabledetails" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">
    <tr class="headerrow">
        <td class="left">Anzahl</td>
        <td class="left">Artikel</td>
        <td class="left">Art.Nr.</td>
        <td class="right">Einzelpreis</td>
        <td class="right">Gesamtpreis</td>
    </tr>
                <tr class="contentrow1">
        <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">1.00 x</td>
        <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">Mavic Rennradschuh Zxellium 2011 black / white / yellow mavic</strong></td>
        <td class="left" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;">14207</td>
        <td class="right" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;"><span class="price"> 220,00 EUR</span></td>
        <td class="right" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 12px !important;"><span class="price"> 220,00 EUR</span></td>
    </tr>
            <tr class="contentrow1">        <td class="right" valign="top"></td>        <td class="left" valign="top">                  <h3>                Schuhgröße:             </h3>                                           </td>       <td class="right" valign="top"></td>        <td class="right" valign="top"></td>        <td class="right" valign="top"></td>    </tr>       <tr class="contentrow1">        <td class="right" valign="top"></td>                        <td class="left" valign="top">                              42                              </td>                                       <td class="right" valign="top"> </td>                           <td class="right" valign="top">                                                                                                                                         </td>                               <td class="right" valign="top">                                                                                 </td>       </tr>   
                <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right" class="subtotal">
        <div align="right">
        <p>Zwischensumme: <span class="price"> 220,00 EUR</span></p>
                        <p>Nachnahme:
        <span class="price"> 3,60 EUR</span></p>
                        <p>DHL - versichert:
        <span class="price"> 0,00 EUR</span></p>
                        <p>inkl. MwSt. 19%:
        <span class="price"> 35,70 EUR</span></p>
                        <p><span class="doubleline">Gesamtsumme: <span class="price"> 223,60 EUR</span></span></p>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is a pain in the a** when it comes to email rendering.

The only safe thing to do is add a `style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"` to every paragraph and div. We all know it sucks - but tell this to Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

Only use inline styles on html emails. It will be stripped out in some email clients. Gmail is one example.

You'll need to add this to every `td` containing text.

```
style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"
```

Comment: as you see i used inline styles with little success, the weird thing is, it works throughout the whole mail but not in the {foreach name=aussen item=order_values from=$order_products}
            <tr class="{cycle values="contentrow1,contentrow2"}"> part (the product loop)

Comment: It doesn't work in the product loop because you didn't define the font-family on the td for the product loop, or the h2, p, or div in the product loop.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to flatten the style classes into inline styles on all the objects.

I had a similar problem and wrote a C# function to flatten the styles into the HTML.

[Flatten CSS into HTML using C# w/ MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533536/flatten-css-into-html-using-c-sharp-w-mvc)