# Flatten CSS into HTML using C# w/ MVC

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm having a small issue with creating emails from HTML and having them display properly in Outlook.

Now we all know Outlook's HTML rendering is somewhat poor. (To be polite!) Basically the best way forward is to bake the style into the HTML elements. However I'd like to take an existing web based report and email it out. Obviously the report is done properly with the style coming from CSS classes.

So what I need to do is parse the HTML page and the CSS and construct a flattened piece HTML which I can mail out.

Using JavaScript and jQuery this would be relatively simple, something along the lines of

```
$("td.baddata").attr("style", "color:red");
```

where obviously changing the selector and style value as you iterate through the CSS.

In researching this issue I've stumbled across the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), however I can't find much in the way of documentation so don't know if you can do something like the above, and would rather not invest the time in learning how it works only to find it isn't up to the job. Can it for example return a collection of elements based on a selector as above? (Presumably I need a DOM Selector to XPath translator?)

Comment: It's not just classes that will be an issue (some clients actually support classes), unless your report is built strictly using tables, it will probably look terrible when rendered out. There is a neat tool in beta at the moment that will take a 'normal' HTML page designed with <div>'s etc.. and convert it to nested tables: [Fractal](http://getfractal.com/). It will also bake in fixes for some of the more common email client quirks.

Comment: Aye, Outlook supports classes, but not multiple classes on the same element. Why would it look different if the CSS was simply baked into the HTML elements? Anyway, the report is mainly tables with the occasional heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after poking around for a while and not finding anything that would obviously do what I wanted, I picked up [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and made my own 'CSS to HTML flattener'. It takes the raw Style text and applies it to the HTML body.

**Please not that is very untested**, uses all sorts of nastiness, and there is probably a much better way to do a lot of it. It also doesn't handle lots of CSS, especially the ':selectors', but it currently works for my purposes so I'm happy.

```
    public static string FlattenCssIntoHtml(string html)
    {
        Regex styleReg = new Regex(@"(.*?)\{(.*?)\}$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        Regex cssReg = new Regex(@"(.*?):(.*?)$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> styleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html[1]/head[1]/style[1]");

        // replace \r's as RegEx only matches \n to newline.
        foreach (Match match in styleReg.Matches(styleNode.First().InnerText.Replace("\r", "")))
        {
            if (match.Groups.Count == 3)
            {
                List<HtmlNode> toSet = FindNodes(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html[1]/body[1]"), match.Groups[1].Value.Trim().Split(' '), 0);

                foreach (Match cssMatch in cssReg.Matches(match.Groups[2].Value))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode thisNode in toSet)
                    {
                        AddStyle(thisNode, cssMatch.Groups[1].Value.Trim(), cssMatch.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }

    private static List<HtmlNode> FindNodes(HtmlNode topNode, string[] toParse, int index)
    {
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> myList;
        string selector = toParse[index];
        string elementName = "";
        string valueName = "";
        int valueType = 0;

        int idx = selector.IndexOfAny(new[] { '.', '#' });
        if (idx > -1)
        {
            elementName = selector.Substring(0, idx);
            valueName = selector.Substring(idx + 1);
            valueType = selector.Substring(idx, 1) == "." ? 1 : 2;
        }
        else
        {
            elementName = selector;
        }

        switch (valueType)
        {
            case 0:
                myList = topNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == elementName);
                break;
            case 1:
                myList = topNode.Descendants().Where(x => (elementName == "" || x.Name == elementName) && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Split().Contains(valueName));
                break;
            case 2:
                myList = topNode.Descendants().Where(x => (elementName == "" || x.Name == elementName) && x.Id == valueName);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        if (index == toParse.Length - 1)
        {
            return new List<HtmlNode>(myList);
        }

        List<HtmlNode> toReturn = new List<HtmlNode>();
        foreach (HtmlNode aNode in myList)
        {
            toReturn.AddRange(FindNodes(aNode, toParse, index + 1));
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private static void AddStyle(HtmlNode dest, string styleName, string styleValue)
    {
        if (!dest.Attributes.Contains("style"))
        {
            dest.Attributes.Add("style", styleName + ":" + styleValue);
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlAttribute attr = dest.Attributes["style"];

            if (!attr.Value.Split().Contains(styleName))
            {
                attr.Value = attr.Value + " " +  styleName + ":" + styleValue;
            }
        }
    }
```